# Simple XSLT modification to get the img src of a tag

Tags: xml, xslt

In the `<content>` tag of a XML among others, there is a

`<img style="styles" src="image.jpg" border="0" alt="">` image I want to get the src.

As for now I add an attribute `img` to the content tag that gets the entire content.

How can I get the image src ?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  >

    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="a:feed/a:entry/a:content">
<content img="{img/@src}"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:entry[position() &gt; 1]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<content img="{img/@src}"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</content>
```

When you know that `img` is a child of the current node, there is no need to wite an absolute Xpath expression -- the relative XPath expression (`img/@src`) is evaluated off the current node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I can't get it right I posted my full XSLT in the answer if I missed something and here is a sample XML I am working on http://feeds.feedburner.com/Kokoraki-KikiriKou?format=xml

Comment: @mtopia: Sorry, but there isn't any XML at that link. Please, provide the XML document as part of your question.

Comment: @mtopia: I see in your code a template that ignores any `a:entry` that isn't the first child of its parent. Probably for the `a:entry` elements that aren't processed by this template, there isn't any `a:content/img/@src` node. Another possibility is that `img` is in the XHTML namespace. Yet another possibility is that despite what you say in the question, `img` isn't a child of `a:content`. As you see, without the XML document one can only try to guess...

Comment: I have pasted here the XML I am working with http://codepad.org/KGP83L14 . This is the original XML but I limited it in one entry.

Comment: @mtopia: As I thought, there isn't any `img` child of `a:content` -- in fact this element doesn't have any child element at all -- it only has one text-node child. What seems as markup there is just escaped/destroyed markup and it cannot be processed with XPath as markup.